# Can this be done by sed?

Tags: bash

Hiall,I need to deal with a file which seems as follows:

```
1234
4343
5345345
53453
4343
```

And what I want to do is to execute follow command to the number of each line:

```
grep $num1 ./somepath  #get num1_res
```

Then write $num1 and $num1_res to another file which will be:

```
1234 32
4343 234
5345345 349
53453 78
#...etc
```

Any good solution by sed?Or some other simple way?

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't explained what num1_res is.

Comment: It's in the comment of second code area:)

Comment: It seems I have a missunderstanding about sed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your requirements are a bit murky, but this should get you most of the way:

```
while read value
do
  echo "$value $(grep "$value" somepath)"
done < somefile
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use awk. (Please try to describe your question more clearly next time). Based upon guesswork of what you want.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{
  list[$0]
  next
}
{
  for(i in list){
    if ( $0~i){
      print i,$0
    }
  }
}
' thelist ./somepath/myfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -f file_with_num1_vals file_with_num1_res_vals
```